# How to write multiple assignments with conditional operator in one line?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logical-operators, conditional-operator

I want to know how can I write those conditional assignments in one line.

Code in my React project:

```
const activeBox = calendarTab ? 'schedule-box active-box' : 'schedule-box';
const engagementBox = engagement ? 'schedule-box active-box' : 'schedule-box';
const scheduleBox = weekSchedule ? 'schedule-box active-box' : 'schedule-box';
```

Comment: Wrap it in a function to make it DRY. You still don't have one line, but why should you?

Comment: Is it not possible to use the same line same code?

Comment: Of course it is. Just write what you have now, but remove the newlines. What were you imagining to gain by this?

Comment: I have three boxed and I want to add ``` active-box  ```  class when I click on any box.

Comment: const [calendarTab, setCalendarTab] = useState(true);

const [engagement, setEngagementTab] = useState(false);

const [weekSchedule, setWeekSchedule] = useState(false);

 const activeBox = calendarTab ? 'schedule-box date-picker active-box' : 'schedule-box date-picker';
  const engagementBox = engagement ? 'schedule-box active-box' : 'schedule-box';
  const scheduleBox = weekSchedule ? 'schedule-box active-box' : 'schedule-box';
export default ScheduleEventBox;


```

Comment: You could put the ternaries in an array and then destructure the array. But it's still unclear what you have to gain by going this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Array#destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [Backtick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). As you are adding `"active-box"` if the condition is true.

```
const isActive = (condition) => condition ? "active-box" : "";

const [activeBox, engagementBox, scheduleBox] = [
      `schedule-box ${isActive(calendarTab)}`,  // This value goes to activeBox variable
      `schedule-box ${isActive(engagement)}`,  // This value goes to engagementBox variable
      `schedule-box ${isActive(weekSchedule)}` // This value goes to scheduleBox variable
]
```

Hope, this may help you.

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully.

Answer (score 1):

One-line solution

Using Object [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const calendarTab = true;
const engagement = false;
const weekSchedule = false;
  
const { activeBox, engagementBox, scheduleBox } = Object.fromEntries(
  [calendarTab, engagement, weekSchedule].map((item, idx) => [
    [`activeBox`, `engagementBox`, `scheduleBox`][idx],
    item ? "schedule-box active-box" : "schedule-box"
  ])
);
  
console.log(activeBox);
console.log(engagementBox);
console.log(scheduleBox);
```

---

You can define a relation list to make it simpler

```js
const data = [
  { id: "calendarTab", value: true, attr: "activeBox" },
  { id: "engagement", value: false, attr: "engagementBox" },
  { id: "weekSchedule", value: false, attr: "scheduleBox" }
];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(x => [
    x.attr,
    x.value ? "schedule-box active-box" : "schedule-box"
  ])
);

console.log(result.activeBox);
console.log(result.engagementBox);
console.log(result.scheduleBox);
```

---

For normal implementation not in one line:

```js
const calendarTab = true;
const engagement = false;
const weekSchedule = false;

const aqClass = value => {
  return value ? "schedule-box active-box" : "schedule-box"
}
const activeBox = aqClass(calendarTab);
const engagementBox = aqClass(engagement);
const scheduleBox = aqClass(weekSchedule)

console.log(activeBox);
console.log(engagementBox);
console.log(scheduleBox);
```